# The way to run method each X minutes

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

It seems like I just need to implement kind of a listener, if there is no something similar already.
Let's say I have a method which is executed each time build finishes (RunListener event); but that's not enough and I want to run the method each X minutes. I'm stuck! 
So, I wonder if there is a way to do it (kind of a listener, event trigger, whatever).
Any info, thoughts are welcomed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to execute a task regularly in a Jenkins plugin, you can implement the [PeriodicWork](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/PeriodicWork.html) extension point.

A minimal example that would automatically register with Jenkins, and be executed every three minutes:

```java
@Extension
public class MyPeriodicTask extends PeriodicWork {

    @Override
    public long getRecurrencePeriod() {
        return TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(3);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doRun() throws Exception {
        // Do something here, quickly.
        // If it will take longer, use AsyncPeriodWork instead
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks! AsyncPeriodicWork seem to do directly what I need.